# Remove padding/margin in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm building a website using Bootstrap 4 and I've noticed that every div has padding and I'm looking for a way to remove it. I've tried to add a class called nopadding with padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; but it doesn't help.
I would love to get some help with it.

Code example (I can click on link even if the mouse is below the link itself):

```css
.credits {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2px;
}

.credits a {
  color: #d5d5d5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.credits a:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="credits">
        <p style="margin-right: 5px;">Inspired by</p>
        <a href="https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/alias/" target="_blank">Bootstrap Website Template</a>
      </div>
      <div class="credits">
        <p style="margin-right: 5px;">Icons from</p>
        <a href="https://fontawesome.com/" target="_blank">Font Awesome</a>
        <p style="margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px;">and</p>
        <a href="https://iconify.design/" target="_blank">Iconify</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it Help https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/?

Comment: You have to know that your line CSS is always stronger than your class CSS

Comment: That's not Bootstrap classes - that is padding from the `p` tag . It is applied to the `a` also because you are using flex.

Comment: Not all divs have padding but only with class like row or col-*. Anyway bootsrap 4 have his own class for this purpose: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/#how-it-works

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove inline styles. To give margin or padding you can use bootstrap classes like i did in below example. For more info [visit bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

```css
.credits {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 2px;
}

.credits a {
  color: #d5d5d5;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.credits a:hover {
  color: #0088a9;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="credits">
        <p class="mr-1">Inspired by</p>
        <a href="https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/alias/" target="_blank">Bootstrap Website Template</a>
      </div>
      <div class="credits">
        <p class="mr-1">Icons from</p>
        <a href="https://fontawesome.com/" target="_blank">Font Awesome</a>
        <p class="mr-1 ml-1">and</p>
        <a href="https://iconify.design/" target="_blank">Iconify</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Alternatively if you need to remove margin, padding from all, you can right like this:**

```
target_element * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put your `a` element in your `p` element as they are in line

```css
.credits
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 2px;
}

.credits a
{
    color: #d5d5d5;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.credits a:hover
{
    color: #0088a9;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
<div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row text-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="credits">
                            <p style="margin-right: 5px;">Inspierd by
                               <a href="https://colorlib.com/preview/theme/alias/" target="_blank">Bootstrap Website Template</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="credits">
                            <p style="margin-right: 5px;">Icons from
                              <a href="https://fontawesome.com/" target="_blank">font awsome</a>
                               and 
                              <a href="https://iconify.design/" target="_blank">iconify</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```